# How to verify if WebElement exist with while loop

Tags: java, selenium, while-loop

I added this to create a random group name, now I want to verify if this group name exists:

```
public String generateRandomName(int length) {
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            .toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        sb.append(c);
    }
    String randomString = sb.toString();
    return randomString;
}
```

This is my while loop:

```
public boolean validateGroupNameIsCorrect(String groupName) {
    int i = 1;
    WebElement NewGroupText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/form/span["+ i + "]"));
    while (true) {
        if (getNewGroupText().getText().equals(groupName));
        return true;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It can't works because it will always check first element + i +

Comment: I know that I should add i++ and else statement, but I am stuck on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xpath to find your element, not need loops:

```
public boolean validateGroupNameIsCorrect(String groupName) {
    return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/form/span[.='"+ groupName + "']")).size()>0;
}
```